# Media query using id selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I recently launched a website and I'm trying to optimize it for mobile display. The majority of the site looks fine on mobile without any media queries but I'm using a jquery lightbox function that I can't quite get to center on mobile displays using media queries. I'm not sure if my syntax is incorrect or if my understanding of how the media query is interacting with the jquery is fundamentally flawed.

The CSS I have at the moment is as follows:

```
#lightbox{position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width:100%;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .95);}

#lightbox img {box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
           -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
           -moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
           height: auto;
           width: 750px;
           margin-top: 2%;
           margin-left: 21%;
           margin-bottom: 2%;}


    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
        #lightbox img {margin-top: 10%;
                       margin-left: 15%;}
    }
}
```

And the Jquery looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e){
                var image_src = $(this).attr("src");
                if($('#lightbox').length > 0) {
                    $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_src + '" />');
                    $('#lightbox').show();
                }
                else{
                    var lightbox =
                    '<div id="lightbox">' + 
                        '<div id="content">' + 
                            '<img src="' + image_src + '" />'
                        '</div>' +  
                    '</div>';
                    $('body').append(lightbox);
                }
            });
            $('#lightbox').live('click', function(){
                $('#lightbox').hide();
            });
        });
```

I've tried several variations such as moving the media query outside the closing bracket of the #lightbox img tag such as:

```
#lightbox{position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width:100%;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .95);}

#lightbox img {box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
           -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
           -moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
           height: auto;
           width: 750px;
           margin-top: 2%;
           margin-left: 21%;
           margin-bottom: 2%;}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
        #lightbox img {margin-top: 10%;
                       margin-left: 15%;}
    }
```

Or getting rid of the #lightbox within the media query, but nothing seems to have an effect on the mobile display. I'm fairly new to web design in general and am having difficulty phrasing my question as I don't really understand what the problem is in the first place. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your media query works just fine. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpRpvV

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work;

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
  #lightbox img {
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
}
```

*Edit;*
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPbpwz

Comment: downvote but no comment? anyway, it's your other css that's messed up. check update.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure who downvoted you, I appreciate your response! But I'm a new user so my reputation isn't high enough to remedy your downvote. But I'm not sure if you're understanding my problem, I want to change the position of the image within the lightbox overlay that displays when an image is selected on mobile display. What you've suggested is what I already have and the image still isn't centered no matter what values I use for margin-top and margin-left.

Comment: @dawgawgawgon the above codepen centers the image no matter the screen size.
I just re-added a media query to reduce max-width to 80% of the screen width on devices with 500px width or lower. in the previously version they took up the entire screen / 100%. I hope it helps, otherwise i don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! I never specified block display so I thought I had to hardcode the margins for different screen sizes, but what you did worked much better thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

```
    @media (max-width: 500px){
          #lightbox img {
          position:absolute;
          top: 10%;
          left: 15%;
      }
}
```

Your JS codes contains too much HTML tags, try to use templating engines, check

[Moustache Js](https://mustache.github.io/)

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted you, I didn't think anyone was going to respond so I'm just checking this now for the first time, thank you for your answer! However, I'm not sure if you're understanding my problem. When I select an image, the lightbox overlay displays and I can't get the image within the lightbox to move using media queries no matter what I try. Even if I add position:absolute; it still has no effect on the mobile lightbox display.

Comment: 2 questions: 

1 is, is the image displaying at all? 
2) if the image is displaying, is it bigger than the screen?

btw, jQuery ".live()" is depreciated, try use the ".on('click', function())"

Comment: The image is displaying and it seems like its proportionally sized for the mobile display compared to a desktop, which I though seemed odd in the first place since I have it hardcoded to be 750px in the CSS without the media query.